# SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL: Query for rows with a specific item in an array

Tags: python, arrays, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to filter PostgreSQL records using SQLALchemy ORM objects based on the existence of an integer variable in an array, but I can't find the right way to do it.

## DB Settings

I have a PostgreSQL table with an [array of integers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/arrays.html):

```
my_db=> \d test_arr;
                           Table "public.test_arr"
  Column  |   Type    |                       Modifiers
----------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer   | not null default nextval('test_arr_id_seq'::regclass)
 partners | integer[] |
```

The table contains some values:

```
my_db=> SELECT * FROM test_arr;
 id | partners
----+----------
 12 | {1,2,3}
 13 | {2,3,4}
 14 | {3,4,5}
 15 | {4,5,6}
(4 rows)
```

Querying the table for the rows which contains the number `2` in the `partners` array is done in PostgreSQL using the `ANY` keyword:

```
my_db=> SELECT * FROM test_arr WHERE 2 = ANY(partners);
 id | partners
----+----------
 12 | {1,2,3}
 13 | {2,3,4}
(2 rows)
```

## ORM with SQLAlchemy

SQLAlchemy [supports PostgreSQL arrays](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types), and the table is represented by:

```
class TestArr(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'test_arr'

    # override schema elements like Columns
    id = Column('id', Integer, Sequence('test_arr_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    partners = Column(ARRAY(Integer))

    def __init__(self, partners):
        self.partners = partners

    def __str__(self):
        return '<%d for %s>' % (self.id, str(self.partners))
```

## The problem

How do I run the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM test_arr WHERE 2 = ANY(partners);` using the Pythonic object?

## What have I tried

I have tried using `func`, like the following:

```
print session.query(TestArr).filter(func.any(TestArr.partners, 2)).all()
```

But failed with Syntax Errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "ANY"
LINE 3: WHERE ANY(test_arr.partners, 332)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use [sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Any](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.Any)

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import Any
session.query(TestArr).filter(Any(2, TestArr.partners)).all()
```

or `@>` array operator

```
session.query(TestArr).filter(TestArr.partners.op('@>')([2])).all()
```

Comment: Syntax I like most is using directly column expression: `session.query(TestArr).filter(TestArr.partners.any(2)).all()`